# How to output eslint errors in the browser when using reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, eslint

Normally i have set up my project using the create-react-app cli tool. 
How can i setup my ReactJS project to output ESLint errors and warnings in the browser. More specifically i want it to output any ESLint errors and warnings just like VueJS does.

VueJS will normally output any warning or error on a semi transparent screen in the browser and will not display the app until you resolve the ESLint errors.

Thank you.

Comment: Why not get your IDE or whatever you're using to show them instead.

Comment: That's good but i like the vue experience much better.

Answer (score 1):

To output eslint errors in the browser you can use the following combination of plugins in `webpack.js`:

```
...
plugins: [
  new ESLintPlugin({
    files: 'src/**/*.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)',
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'],
    configFile: '.eslintrc.json',
    lintDirtyModulesOnly: true,
    emitError: true,
    emitWarning: true,
    failOnError: false,
    failOnWarning: false,
  }),
  new ErrorOverlayPlugin(),
  new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin({}),
],
...
```

Assumptions:

- you use webpack.js as a bundle tool
- you have configured `.eslintrc.json` for your project
- you have installed and imported `ESLintPlugin` and `ErrorOverlayPlugin` into your webpack.js file